# Undefined is not an object for react navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-props

I have two components for my project, and I have gone through all the steps for react navigation as follow:

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import Main from './app/componenets/Main'
import details from './app/componenets/details'
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'

const mainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MainScreen: Main,
    detailsScreen: details,
  },
  {
   initialRouteName :'MainScreen'
  }
);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(mainNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component{

render() {
return(
  <AppContainer />
);
}
}
```

Then I have my Main.js which I have a method as follow:

```
    import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet ,
     Text,
     View, 
    } from 'react-native'
import Note from './Note'
import detail from './details'
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";


export default class Main extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'To do list',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
    },
  };

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      noteArray: [],
      noteText: ''
    }
  }

render() {
    let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val,key) => {
      return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
      goToDetailPage= {() => this.goToNoteDetail(key)} />
    });
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.footer}>
                <TextInput
                onChangeText={(noteText) => this.setState({noteText})}
                style={styles.textInput}
                placeholder='What is your next Task?'
                placeholderTextColor='white'
                underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
                >
                </TextInput>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addNote.bind(this)} style={styles.addButton}>
                <Text style={styles.addButtonText}> + </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    }
    //This method is declared in my Note.js
    goToNoteDetail=(key)=>{   
      this.props.navigation.navigate('detailsScreen')
      }
}
```

//Styles which I didn't post to be short in code here
But when I try to do the navigation I get this error:
'undefined is not and object(evaluating 'this.props.val.date')
Do I need to pass the props in a way? or should I do anything else? I am new to React native and confused!

Answer (score 0):

in order to access this.props make arrow function or bind the function in constructor.

```
goToDetail=()=>{   
this.props.navigation.navigate('detailsScreen')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't change my error and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `createAppContainer`

```
const AppContainer = mainNavigator;
```

and tell me what `react-navigation` that you work with

Comment: I did but I got this error:
' The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. in react-navigation 3 you must set up you app container directly'

Comment: ok, in v3 you need `createAppContainer`
can you share Main code ? and try to console log navigation there and tell what the output

Comment: I have edited my question and post Main.js code. I ignore some codes which are not neccessary for my question

Comment: please try console log `this.props.navigation` inside `goToDetails` and tell me what you get

Comment: It says undefined!

Comment: I found the problem, everything was fine but my details class name was wrong inside the code, I changes it and now it works

Comment: great! when you said you got `undefined` we can know is not navigation problem

Comment: my pleasure :)  .